# SIFR3 vs JQuery SIFR

Tags: jquery, sifr

jQuery SIFR reads the style of a selector directly from the CSS. So there is no need to configure this manually as you would in vanilla SIFR.

```
sIFR.replace(futura, {
  selector: 'h1',
  css: '.sIFR-root { background-color: #F9F9F9; color: #FF0000; }' // <---
});
```

I looked through the SIFR3 docs, but I can't find a command that achieves this.
Is it possible to make SIFR3 look at the stylesheet directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without coding for it. This is because sIFR also takes a few non-standard CSS properties that are send to Flash. The jQuery port skips over a lot of these more subtle things.